# Is there a way to set a `--cfg` flag only for specific target in .cargo/config.toml?

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo, buildconfiguration

I'd like to pass a custom `--cfg` flag to `rustc` via Cargo. Normally, I can do this by putting this in `.cargo/config` for a given crate:

```ini
[build]
rustflags = "--cfg procmacro2_semver_exempt"
```

However, in one of my crates, I am using a custom compilation `target`, and that seems to break `rustflags`;

```ini
[build]
target = "avr-atmega32u4.json"
rustflags = "--cfg procmacro2_semver_exempt"

[unstable]
build-std = ["core"]

[env]
AVR_CPU_FREQUENCY_HZ = "16_000_000"
```

In this case, the config flag is not passed to `rustc`. I've tried moving `rustflags` into a target-specific section:

```ini
[target.avr-atmega32u4.json]
rustflags = "--cfg procmacro2_semver_exempt"
```

but this doesn't seem to have any effect either.

Comment: this work however "avr-atmega32u4.json" is not a valid triple target. https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#configuration-format

Comment: @Stargateur so how do I refer to a target that is specified in a `.json` file?

Comment: that far belong my knowledge of cargo, I got no idea, notice the doc say to use an array so maybe try `rustflags = ["--cfg", "procmacro2_semver_exempt"]`

Comment: @Stargateur I found in [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#target) that it should be `[target.avr-atmega32u4]` (without the `.json` filename extension), *but* even using that it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Stargateur can you show a complete example that sets the `target` to a "stock" target triple, and successfully sets `rustflags`?